# Simulation in energy efficiency in Grid

Tags: networking, simulation, simulator, networkstream, energy

i am planning to do my grad project on energy efficiency in Grid networks with data streaming. my plan is to simulate the movement of data and calculate energy consumption in the network. before starting any coding i would like to select a simulation tool which support data stream in large-scale networks and energy issue. I am thinking about using ns2 or GridSim. But before choosing one, I would like to know of any other simulators that i can use. What is the best simulation tool to support energy issue and data flow for large-scale data-intensive networks?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Gridsim provides better functionalities. Gridsim package contains some examples on how to use the GridSim toolkit. Go through these example, and then you can decide whether it suits to you based on the work you suppose to do. You can design a very large network for sending and receiving gridlets and datagridlets for job scheduling and file operations at any resource (append, delete, add, etc.), respectively. Here is a lsit of Gridsim examples:

gridsim/example01: 
    shows how to create one Grid resource with three machines.

gridsim/example02: 
    shows how to create one or more Grid users. A Grid user
    contains one or more Gridlets. Therefore, this example also shows
    how to create Gridlets with and without using GridSimRandom class.

gridsim/example03: 
    shows how two GridSim entities interact with each other.

gridsim/example04: 
    shows how a grid user submits its Gridlets or tasks to one grid
    resource entity.

gridsim/example05: 
    shows how a grid user submits its Gridlets or tasks to many grid
    resource entities.

gridsim/example06: 
    shows how one or more grid user submits its Gridlets or tasks to
    many grid resource entities.

gridsim/example07: 
    shows how to migrate Gridlets and other stuff such as
    cancel/pause/resume.

gridsim/example08: 
    shows how to make a new and simple grid resource scheduler.

gridsim/example09:
    shows how to make new GridResource and GridInformationService entities.

gridsim/example10: 
    shows how to use Advanced Reservation functionalities.

gridsim/regionalGIS: 
    shows how to create multiple regional GridInformationService
    (GIS) entities in a network topology.

auction: 
    shows few examples how to use the auction extension of GridSim.

dataGrid: 
    shows few examples how to use the datagrid extension of GridSim.

network: 
    shows few examples how to use the network extension of GridSim.

ResFailure: 
    shows how to use the resource failures of GridSim.

WorkloadTrace: 
    shows few examples how to use workload traces from a file in GridSim.

parallel:
    Illustrates how to model clusters/supercomputers that process 
    parallel jobs. To run most examples, you will need to inform the
    path to a workload file that contains the information on the jobs
    submitted to the cluster. For example, in order to run the EASY 
    backfilling example on Linux, you should use:

```
java -cp $GRIDSIM/jars/gridsim.jar:. \
        parallel.agressive.ExampleEASY01 parallel/sdsc_blue_01.txt
```

parallel/util:
    shows how to use two different workload models for the parallel jobs in GridSim.
    These workloads are as follows:
    1. Lublin model: workload for supercomputers
    2. DAS2 model: workload for multi-clusters

fta:
    shows how to use the Failure Trace Archive (FTA) for the simulation of resource failure.
    The provided packages read the tabbed version of the failure traces and generate 
    a list of events that show the availability/unavailability pattern for each machine 
    in a grid resource. 
    see the FTA web site for more information about the traces at: http://fta.inria.fr.
    to run the example, you should use:

```
java -cp $GRIDSIM/jars/gridsim.jar:. fta.FTAExample01 \
            $GRIDSIM/examples/fta/workload_bot.txt  $GRIDSIM/examples/fta/fta_tab
```